# How to delegate from TZ1 address via command line

Tags: tezos-client, transactions, delegating, transfer, ubuntu

How do you delegate from a TZ1 address via command line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [command line interface reference](http://tezos.gitlab.io/api/cli-commands.html), also accessible through `tezos-client man -v 3`:

```
tezos-client set delegate for <src> to <mgr>
```

`src` is your `tz1`, `mgr` is the baker's address.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try

Comment: @MackBaise Be sure to mark this as answered